# Simulating responses from third party server in Django

Tags: python, django, django-testing, django-unittest

I have a function that makes a call :

```
GET www.thirdpartydomain.com/objectlist/
```

and fetches a JSON list in the following way:
[
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'abc',
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'def',
    }
]

and then the function loops through the objects in the array fetched and makes further calls

```
GET www.thirdpartydomain.com/object/<id> --- where id is in the fetched json array
```

For testing, I dont want to call the thirdpartydomain API and instead fake it with known responses for LISt and DETAILS API

How can I do this in Django?

Comment: I'd say it mostly depends on how you are sending the request to the third party website. If you are using the module [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) you can use the module [`responses`](https://github.com/getsentry/responses) to "fake" the HTTP request and get the results you want for testing.

Comment: +1 for `responses` ... there's also https://pypi.python.org/pypi/httpretty they are both good but different, have used them both

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Betamax](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/betamax/0.1.6)? To quote from the documentation:

> Betamax intercepts every request you make and attempts to find a
>   matching request that has already been intercepted and recorded

You'd decorate your tests appropriate, the the first time you run them it would mock them from what it recorded previously.